# Apache Hive: LOAD DATA vs INSERT OVERWRITE OUTPUT FILE SIZE

Tags: hadoop, hive, size, output

I am working with Apache Hive and I don't understand why the size of the table doubles if I load the data with INSERT OVERWRITE vs LOAD. As follows is an illustration of the problem:

I created a table item
Loaded the data from item.dat (aprox 28MB)
In Azzure what happens is that the file item.dat will be moved to hive/warehouse and off course the size remains the same

Now if I create another table item2 same as item and then load the data from item to item2 with the following command:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE item2
SELECT * FROM item
```

the size of table item2 is double of item (aprox 55MB)

Why does this happen? And is there any way to avoid it?

ps. this is only to illustrate the problem. In practice I am interested for pre-joining tables but INSERT OVERWRITE increases the size of the joined table drastically (Actual problem: 4GB joined with 28MB gives 18GB)

Answer (score 2):

Solved the mistery :)

The problem was created by some of the fields of the table being of type char.

When populating the table with INSERT OVERWRITE, for all fields of type char(50), even if the values were less then 50, it will automatically add empty characters to fill the whole space reserved for the char data type. And this is actually the main difference between char and varchar. The later will occupy a variable amount of space based on the value stored. But another question that comes up is why this does not happen when using LOAD

However, at least I know why it happened and managed to avoid it by changing char to varchar data type...So pay attention to the data type ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the storage of table item is compressed, and you use "insert overwrite" **depress** the data of item, then insert the depressed data into table item2.

Comment: I used the same syntax when creating the tables: CREATE TABLE ( field1, field 2,...) row format delimited fields terminated by '|'
lines terminated by '\n' ... probably is something related with the format of the data ...the "load" reads it from a text file dhe "insert overwrite" queries a table.. I don't know whether there might be a workaround for this

Comment: what is structure of this item.dat file?

Comment: It is a text file with field delimited with |

Comment: Latest update on the issue:

I tested on cloudera as well and it is the same behavior: As follows are the settings that differ after running describe formatted <table_name> :

item (with LOAD):

numRows 0
rawDataSize 0
totalSize 28855325
transient_lastDdlTime 1427988576

item2 (with INSERT OVERWRITE):

numRows 102000
rawDataSize 52058005
totalSize 52160005
transient_lastDdlTime 1427990208

And now I don’t understand why the number of rows is 0 for item. When I query it returns 102000 rows